# Testing stop behavior of an EventSourcedBehavior in akka

Tags: akka, akka-persistence, akka-testkit

I have an EventSourcedBehavior that will eventually get a message which leads to one last event and then stops itself. Implementing this is not the problem, but when I want to test it I get a DeadLetter Message because the EventSourcedBehaviorTestKit sends a "GetState" message right after the runCommand. Problem is: the behavior stopped itself and cannot respond anymore.

I have looked into the api docs of EventSourcedBehaviorTestKit but cannot find a suitable method to achieve my goal.

Here is a simple test that showcases my problem:

```
"test behavior stop" in {
    sealed trait Command
    case object Hi extends Command

    sealed trait Event

    sealed trait State
    case object Empty extends State

    val behavior = EventSourcedBehavior[Command, Event, State](
        PersistenceId.ofUniqueId("1"), 
        Empty, 
        (_,_) => Effect.none.thenStop(), 
        (_,_) => Empty)

    val kit = EventSourcedBehaviorTestKit[Command, Event, State](system, behavior)
    kit.runCommand(Hi)              
}
```

```
[2022-10-31 19:30:30,059] [INFO] [akka.actor.LocalActorRef] [SomeSpec-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://SomeSpec/system/test/$a] - Message [akka.persistence.typed.internal.EventSourcedBehaviorImpl$GetState] to Actor[akka://SomeSpec/system/test/$a#-553414380] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. If this is not an expected behavior then Actor[akka://SomeSpec/system/test/$a#-553414380] may have terminated unexpectedly. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

```
- must test behavior stop *** FAILED ***
[info]   java.lang.AssertionError: Timeout (3 seconds) during receiveMessage while waiting for message.
[...]
```

```
build.sbt
---------
...

lazy val akkaVersion = 2.6.19

"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor-testkit-typed" % akkaVersion     % Test,
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-persistence-testkit" % akkaVersion     % Test,
"org.scalatest"     %% "scalatest"                % "3.1.4"         % Test
...
```

How can I setup the test so that I can run this command and then expect the behavior to stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stopping is not testable with the `EventSourcedBehaviorTestKit`.

You can leverage the [`PersistentTestKit`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.6/typed/persistence-testing.html#persistence-testkit)'s in-memory journal and snapshot store and test using the `ActorTestKit`.

Alternatively, as of Akka 2.7.0, there's the ability to [turn an `EventSourcedBehavior` into one that doesn't persist but exposes events and snapshots on probes](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/persistence-testing.html#unit-testing-with-the-behaviortestkit) (instead of the secret `GetState` command as the `EventSourcedBehaviorTestkit` does) and is testable using the `BehaviorTestkit` or `ActorTestkit` (though the ergonomics favor the former).

Comment: I answered from mobile, so couldn't post links, so I've since updated with links.